# Iterate through all tags within found tag

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

How can I iterate through all tags under the found tag?

This gives me only top level tags

```
description = soup.find("div", {"class": "description"})
for tag in description:
    print(tag)
```

This gives me iteration until the end of html

```
description = soup.find("div", {"class": "description"})
while description:
    description = description.next_element
    print(description)
```

Answer (score 1):

`description` is not iterable, because `find()` method returns the first selected tag from soup, so comes use the `findAll()` method.

```
descriptions = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "description"})
for description in descriptions:
    print(description)
```

Answer (score 0):

are you looking for `.descendants`?

```
description = soup.find("div", {"class": "description"})
for tag in description.descendants:
    print(tag)
```